# How to exchange the ordered products in spree commerce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In spree commerce, from the customer end, after buying a product, is there any ways to exchange the ordered products .

Comment: What exactly do you mean and at what point in the order process?

Comment: Once the order process is complete a customer should able to exchange the product is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

In Spree 2.4+ there are exchanges.  Within the admin you create a customer return, and specify what from their order they returned.  Then you can either select another item to exchange or you can refund them for the return.  It's not covered very well by the guides but does exist, which you can feel free to submit a PR updating them for any clarity you need:
https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/returning_orders.html